# Torsion Modules Annihilators

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, torsion-groups

Let $R$ be a PID, let $B$ be a torsion $R$-module, and let $p$ be a prime in $R$. Show that if $pb = 0$ for some nonzero $b \in B$, then $\operatorname{Ann}(B)$ is a subset of $(p)$.

Well we can let $\operatorname{Ann}(B) = (t)$ for some $t \in R$ since it is an ideal in $R$. How to make use of the fact that $B$ is torsion (i.e. there is r in R such that rm=0 for each m in M) to prove the desired result?

Comment: The assumption that $B$ is torsion is actually totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $\operatorname{Ann}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}(b)$, it suffices to show $\operatorname{Ann}(b)=(p)$.

A stronger hint is hidden below.

> Since $pb=0$, $(p)\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}(b)$.  That is, $\operatorname{Ann}(b)$ is an ideal which contains $(p)$.  What ideals are there which contain $(p)$?

Comment: Just came across this post now...the answer to the question in your hint is: $(p)$ or $R$. Now if it is $(p)$ we are done, but what if $\text{Ann}(b)$ is $R$?

Comment: Remember that $b$ is assumed to be nonzero.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But $b\neq0_M$ doesn't preclude $\text{Ann}(b)$ from being all of $R$, does it?

Comment: If $b\neq 0$, then $1\cdot b\neq 0$, so $1\not\in\text{Ann}(b)$.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much.